# pom.xml dependencies for spark while using scala 2.12.10

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, dependencies, pom.xml

These Apache Spark dependencies are not working, while working with scala 2.12.10

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Error while running spark app from IntelliJ

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V    at
> org.apache.spark.SparkConf$DeprecatedConfig.(SparkConf.scala:784)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.(SparkConf.scala:605)  at
> org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.(SparkConf.scala)     at
> org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:94)    at
> org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:83)    at
> org.apache.spark.SparkConf.setMaster(SparkConf.scala:115)     at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.updatedConf(SparkContext.scala:2717)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:153)

However, this set of dependencies work perfectly fine with the same spark app.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code snippet -

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
object Testing1
    {
      def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {
        Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
        val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]" , "SparkDemo")
        val lines = sc.textFile("sample.txt");
        val words = lines.flatMap(line => line.split(' '))
        val wordsKVRdd = words.map(x => (x,1))
        val count = wordsKVRdd.reduceByKey((x,y) => x + y).map(x => (x._2,x._1)).sortByKey(false).map(x => (x._2, x._1)).take(10)
        count.foreach(println)
      }
    }
```

Comment: what does mean "not working"? please add error or warning or something like. And piece of code

Comment: @AlexOtt - Updated with error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This errors says about Scala version incompatibility. You either have another dependency that depends on the Scala 2.11, or you just need to do `mvn clean` to get rid of the old classes compiled with Scala 2.11.  Also check the version of Scala configured in the Project's settings.

Answer (score 1):

It started working after I added scala 2.12.10 sdk in the module settings in IntelliJ. Also, I deleted scala 2.11.8 sdk from the module/project settings.

Comment: Same here. I got the same error and had two Scala SDKs in my IntelliJ Project settings (Scala 11 and 12)